# Need assistance to press letters from keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am making a word guessing game

[image: word guessing game]

and this is the html for the keyboard

```
<div id="qwerty" class="section">
            <div class="keyrow">
                <button class="key">q</button>
                <button class="key">w</button>
                <button class="key">e</button>
                <button class="key">r</button>
                <button class="key">t</button>
                <button class="key">y</button>
                <button class="key">u</button>
                <button class="key">i</button>
                <button class="key">o</button>
                <button class="key">p</button>
```

what I would like to be able to do is to use regex in order to be able to make guesses by being able to press keys from physical keyboard

this is what I have :

```
    //Allow player to use physical keyboard to guess letters
$('.key').keypress(function() {
if ('.key' === [a-zA-Z]) {
console.log('a key was pressed from the physical keyboard')
}

});
```

I would like to use my laptop's keyboard to click on a letter only and try to guess a phrase in the game besides just using the mouse to play

[![Using physical keyboard to play game
][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZrPq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZrPq.png)

can someone help?

Comment: do you want to print the character which user pressed?

Comment: well not really, I use console.log to help me with figuring if syntax works or not, along with visually seeing what each function does, what I want to do is trigger the effect of the letters being pressed from a physical keyboard instead of using the mouse to click the in-game keyboard

Comment: I see that regex can be used to restrict certain kinds of input, I figured that I might also be able to use keypress along with [a-zA-Z], but since I see that most people used regex on forms instead of buttons, I am unsure as to how to proceed from what I already have

Comment: It seems like you can remove almost your entire question, and just ask "How can I find out if a pressed keyboard key matches a regular expression?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are retrieving user input via the keyboard then you need to be aware that keys in javascript have unique numbers instead of letter representations. So to check if a letter key was pressed you need to convert the key code (number) to a letter using `String.fromCharCode` and then check if the letter matches your regular expression using `.test()`.

However, instead of transforming the `key` number to a string yourself, you can instead just use `e.key` to get the character version of the key pressed instead of the number.

See working example below:

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  let key = e.key;
  if (/^[A-Za-z]$/.test(key)) {
    keyPressFunc(key); // Run the key press/typed section of code
  }
});

$('.key').click(function() {
  let key = $(this).text(); // Get the text (letter) of the element you clicked on (this)
  keyPressFunc(key); // Run the key press/typed section of code
});


// The code to run when a key is either pressed or typed
function keyPressFunc(letter) {
  console.log("The key pressed was " +letter);
  console.log("This code runs wen you type or click a letter");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="qwerty" class="section">
  <div class="keyrow">
    <button class="key">q</button>
    <button class="key">w</button>
    <button class="key">e</button>
    <button class="key">r</button>
    <button class="key">t</button>
    <button class="key">y</button>
    <button class="key">u</button>
    <button class="key">i</button>
    <button class="key">o</button>
    <button class="key">p</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, if you wish to get user input via the button clicks in your game you can use jQuery's `.click()` method to detect when the user clicks on an element with the class `key`. You can then use the `this` keyword to refer to the button/element which was pressed and use `.text()` to retrieve the HTML text held within the button element which was clicked.

See example below:

```js
$('.key').click(function() {
  let key = $(this).text(); // Get the text (letter) of the element you clicked on (this)
  console.log("You picked letter: " +key);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="qwerty" class="section">
  <div class="keyrow">
    <button class="key">q</button>
    <button class="key">w</button>
    <button class="key">e</button>
    <button class="key">r</button>
    <button class="key">t</button>
    <button class="key">y</button>
    <button class="key">u</button>
    <button class="key">i</button>
    <button class="key">o</button>
    <button class="key">p</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't know that keys have unique numbers, I guess that you learn something new every day

Comment: @ErikL yep :P many things in programming have numbers associated with them. Did this solve your question?

Comment: but in my case in which I have buttons, how would I be able to retrieve the the 'presses' that a player makes in my game?

Comment: I tried your example, but I can't seem to trigger the effect of the keys being pressed on the in-game buttons using my keyboard

Comment: @ErikL hey, I've editted my answer for the keys being click. The `keypress` method only triggers when the user presses a key on their keyboard. So instead you need to add a `.click()` method for when the user clicks a key on your HTML in-game board. For this case though, you do not need to do a regex check for the letter, as you know the user will only be able to click one of the letters on your game board. Thus, if you want both keyboard input and in-game UI input you can use both of the methods I provided above

Comment: @ Nick ParsonsI think there has been a little misunderstanding, when I said that I wanted the player's input, I meant to being able to press a key in a physical keyboard in order to try and play and reveal the letter in the phrase, just as I would be able to use my mouse to click on the letters in the game, I want to use my keyboard to click on them. I added another picture to show. My apologies for not being clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185308/discussion-between-nick-parsons-and-erik-l).

Comment: Note that jQery not withstanding,  [KeyboardEvent.which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) has been deprecated in favor of the non-numeric [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) .